# Software to send push notifications at scheduled times

Tags: android, java, ios, swift

I'm currently looking for recommendations on how to implement a way of sending push notifications to users and their selected times using some sort of server or framework or SDK (Examples would be firebase, Batch.com, etc.)

I'm developing an app in swift (and soon to be android) and what I want to do find something that is able to do the following things

My requirements are:

1. Be able to handle multiple users who schedule multiple notifications at different times to be delivered to the respective users at their respective times.
2. Upon receiving the notification run a function in the background of my application.
3. Be able to scale up by adding more users.
4. Be relatively affordable

Comment: In general, push technology is not very advanced/ stable. The usual approach is for the clients to poll the server. I look forward to someone proving me wrong, btw, as I would love a stable server push, but always come back to client side polling.